# Doing an action in Rails without changing site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good day...

Still a beginner question. I mostly asking to save myself hours of trial and error... I had those already and there was no result.

What I wanna do... I have a controller that has an action, of course. I want to send this action two IDs, it should make some database entry of those. No problem, the action works well.

But I don't want a view to it, I want the user to click on a link and not even leave the site. Ideally there should be some Ajax (using jQuery a lot on the site) that changes the link to a 'Thanks' or anything.

So yes, my main question is: How can I activate an action of an other controller without leaving the site, from a link. Long intro, but I hope you can give me some hints.

Comment: You might get a better response if you are more specific and include some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [link_to_remote](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote) for the view side and then you can just have your controller function `render nothing => true`.

Comment: Normally you would render something, preferably some js that updates your page, notifies you something has been done, stops your spinner.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it un-obtrusive & return something from the controller action... I think you probably want something like:

```
def my_action
  # your code...  e.g. @model = Model.find(params[:id])

  render :json => { :whatever => @model.whatever }
end
```

In your javascript, do what thou wilt with the returned information & prevent the default action of your hyperlink by returning false or using jQuery's prevent default functionality for the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `link_to_remote` method in rails. That should make an ajax call out to a controller function and not leave the page.

Comment: Nope. link_to_function runs javascript.

Comment: Whoops, was thinking `link_to_remote` and typed out `function`.